# Python: linecache file size limit?

Tags: python, linecache

I have a pretty big .txt file. Each entry is on a new line. I am trying to access the file and iterate through each line to grab the entry. However when I use `linecache.getline('file_path', 1)`, I am getting an empty string. Which from the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/linecache.html), is how `linecache` returns errors. Is there a file size limit? I am trying to read a 1.2GB file. I am also fairly sure `linecache` is still trying to read the whole file into memory before getting a line number. RAM usage goes up about the size of the file and then returns to normal. Anything I'm doing wrong with `linecache`? Any suggestions other than `linecache`?

Comment: You want to load entire file into memory at once, or just line by line reading without loading entire file

Comment: Line by line without loading the whole file. This file is going to be open for a couple weeks while a program goes through and does functions on each entry. It'd be nice if I wasn't using 1-2GB of RAM for 2 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to read a file line by line, without loading it into memory, the python `open` comes with its own generator for exactly this.

```py
with open("filename", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        # Do stuff
```

As long as you do what you have to do inside that `for` loop, you don't have to worry about memory.

More info on the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Comment: This is great. My only concern is that there isn't a way to specify a start of the for loop. These programs crash sometimes and I'd like a way to see where it crashed and just restart at that entry.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use the file object as an iterator.

```
for line in open("log.txt"):
    do_something_with(line)
```

#### Even better is using context manager in Python versions.

```
with open("log.txt") as fileobject:
    for line in fileobject:
        do_something_with(line)
```

This will automatically close the file as well.